# ObservableCollection<T> : Differentiate between Re-order and Remove

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

How to differentiate between *Re-order* and *Remove* of a `GridViewItem` from a `GridView` inside `CollectionChanged` event?

```
void gridView_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
   //e seems to be same for Re-order and Remove
}
```

Any suggestion please?

Comment: How are you "re-ordering" you collection. Intrinsicly this involves either creating a new reordered collection or moving items about. If it is the latter then `e.Action` will be `Move`.

Comment: @BenRobinson I am not doing anything currently. The `ObservableCollection<T>` is directly bound to the `GridView` and `CollectionChanged` is being raised when `GridViewItem`s are dragged or if I remove an element from the bound data source. But for both the `e.Action` is __Remove__ at first. So, how do I differentiate?

Comment: Are you using a PCL to hold the ObservableCollection? or is it directly in your WinRT code?

Comment: Its in a separate class lib and using it in a WinRT app.